# GTK allow open files with new vala application

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala, freedesktop.org, elementary-os

I'm developing a media player with Vala and I want to be able to open audio files with this application (once it is installed).

In .descktop files I added the following MIME types to indicate which files can open (they are the same MIME types than in banshee):

```
MimeType=application/musepack;application/ogg;application/rss+xml;application/vnd.emusic-emusic_list;application/x-ape;application/x-democracy;application/x-extension-m4a;application/x-extension-mp4;application/x-flac;application/x-flash-video;application/x-id3;application/x-linguist;application/x-matroska;application/x-miro;application/x-musepack;application/x-netshow-channel;application/x-ogg;application/x-quicktime-media-link;application/x-quicktimeplayer;application/x-shorten;application/x-troff-msvideo;application/xspf+xml;audio/3gpp;audio/AMR;audio/AMR-WB;audio/ac3;audio/ape;audio/avi;audio/basic;audio/flac;audio/midi;audio/mp;audio/mp2;audio/mp3;audio/mp4;audio/mp4a-latm;audio/mpc;audio/mpeg;audio/mpeg3;audio/mpegurl;audio/musepack;audio/ogg;audio/vorbis;audio/wav;audio/wave;audio/x-amzxml;audio/x-ape;audio/x-flac;audio/x-it;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-matroska;audio/x-mod;audio/x-mp;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpc;audio/x-mpeg;audio/x-mpeg-3;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-ogg;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;audio/x-s3m;audio/x-sbc;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-speex;audio/x-tta;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wavpack;audio/x-xm;image/avi;image/x-pict;misc/ultravox;text/google-video-pointer;text/x-google-video-pointer;text/x-opml+xml;video/3gpp;video/avi;video/dv;video/fli;video/flv;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;video/mpeg;video/msvideo;video/ogg;video/quicktime;video/vivo;video/vnd.divx;video/vnd.vivo;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;video/x-flic;video/x-flv;video/x-m4v;video/x-matroska;video/x-mpeg;video/x-mpg;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-wm;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-wmx;video/x-ms-wvx;video/x-msvideo;video/x-nsv;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/x-theora;video/x-theora+ogg;x-scheme-handler/lastfm;x-scheme-handler/u1ms;
```

By donig this the application is shown in the dialog "Open with" when I click on a file.

Then, in my Gtk.Application class I added in the constructor:

```
class SomeClass (string[] args) { 
    Object (application_id: "some.id", flags: ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_OPEN);
    // do stuff...
}
```

And finally I added the "open" method which is suposed to be called when a file is open with the aplication:

```
public override void open (File[] files, string hint) {
    // do stuff ...
}
```

However, when I try to open a .mp3 file with my application appears a dialog which says:

"No es poden obrir els fitxers o uris amb aquesta aplicació"

in english:

"The files or uris can not be opened with this application"

So my question is: Am I missing something?

I've added MIME types in descktop file, I've activated the flag "HANDLES_OPEN" and I've implemented the method "open".

PD: I'm working with elementaryOS and I install my app with CMake build system.

Answer (score 0):

In GLib/C terminology: You need to *connect* your implementation of `open` to the `GApplication`'s [`::open` signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html#GApplication-open).

In Vala terminology: See [signals](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/SignalsAndCallbacks):

```
class Foo : Object {
    public signal void some_event ();   // definition of the signal

    public void method () {
        some_event ();                  // emitting the signal (callbacks get invoked)
    }
}

void callback_a () {
    stdout.printf ("Callback A\n");
}

void callback_b () {
    stdout.printf ("Callback B\n");
}

void main () {
    var foo = new Foo ();
    foo.some_event.connect (callback_a);      // connecting the callback functions
    foo.some_event.connect (callback_b);
    foo.method ();
}
```

...

So, in Vala terms:

- You need a reference to a [GLib.Application](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.Application.html).
- You need to call [`app.connect(open);`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.Application.open.html) somewhere before your mainloop starts running.